# Which data structures are using how much memory

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, memory-management

I'm writing a C++ program which is using more memory than I expected (as measured by e.g. the Linux `top` command); it matters in this case because available memory is an important limiting factor on the program's capabilities. Is there a way to tell which data structures (classes or objects) account for how much of the memory usage?

That is, of course I could wrap each object in code to track its memory usage individually, but I'm wondering is there a more automated solution using existing tools such as `gdb` or `valgrind`?

Comment: You might possibly be having memory leaks in your program. Run valgrind with memecheck, it might be helpful. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

In code, you can just use the `sizeof` function.

If you need a tool, you can just look for "Profiling tool C++" on your favorite search engine. You gonna have a lot of results.